# Airflow Get Rows Affected from Postgres Operator

Tags: postgresql, airflow

My Airflow DAG has a Postgres Operator that I would like to know how many rows it affecting. Here is an example of my task:

```
task4 = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='empty_staging',
    sql='DELETE FROM staging.table',
    postgres_conn_id='some_db_conn',
    autocommit=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

When this task is executed, this is all that is left in the logs:

```
[2019-10-29 15:08:43,944] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-10-29 15:08:43,943[0m] {[34mlocal_task_job.py:[0m105} INFO[0m - Task exited with return code 0[0m
```

As far as I can tell, there's no pr-baked way to record rows affected in the Postgres Operator? How do I log what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "returning *" -- it'll return all the data that was deleted so you can count the array at that point to get a count.

```
 sql='DELETE FROM staging.table returning *',
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? I'm really sure I understand,

Comment: I changed my query to yours, but it didn't actually return anything in the logs. Was there another step I missed?

Comment: Perhaps.. this just makes the data available to you.. you still have to get the results, usually through a fetch type of command to get the data and do something with it. The "delete" command now (perhaps not so obviously) returns results in addition to just running the command.. it returns all of the data it just deleted.

Comment: I mean my question is specifically for the postgres operator. So is it not possible with this operator?

Comment: You're referencing a log file... is this a postgres log file you're talking about? It looks like it might be a log for something else

Comment: My questions for the postgres operator in airflow. It executes a sql query, but it doesnt log how many rows are affected when it executes.